# ms project vba not changing cell color

Tags: vba, ms-project

UPDATE:  Answered below

In MS Project 2013 Pro, I created a custom field "Pri" (for priority) from the  "Number10" field.   Then I wrote the VBA routine below, which is activated from a button on a VBA form, to check the value of Pri and set the cell color accordingly.  It works, except...

When I set the value of Pri, and run the routine, and then reset the value of Pri, and re-run the routine, it doesn't "take".  I can tell in watch that it has found the field, detected a "Select Case" value, and executed the CellColor assignment statement.  But the color of the cell doesn't change in the Gantt Chart view.

I'm looking for a pattern here, and what I can see is:
1) If I update Pri the field (i.e. change the value after the first add), and then update **another** task Pri field, it immediately applies the background to the one I wanted first wanted to change.
2)  the newly updated Pri cell has a faint blue background;  is that some sort of "tentative" status?  Which might not be read by VBA?  If so, how to "refresh" or whatever to get the app to accept the value?
=> this appears to be "Change Highlighting" described [here](http://zo-d.com/blog/archives/project-2007/ms-project-2007-change-highlighting-and-the-interim-plan.html);  what might be done with that?
3) if I open and close the Outline section that contains the task, it sets the color correctly. Again, some kind of refresh?  More Change Highlighting?

I added the ScreenUpdating = False/True lines at the beginning, in response to a bug report, however, no joy.

==> Any suggestions?

```
Sub SetPriorityColors()

ScreenUpdating = False
ScreenUpdating = True

Set ts = ActiveProject.Tasks
For n = 1 To ts.Count
If Not ts(n) Is Nothing Then
    ts(n).OutlineShowAllTasks
End If
Next n

For n = 1 To ts.Count
If Not ts(n) Is Nothing Then
    Set tsk = ts(n)
    wrkName = tsk.Name
    wrkID = tsk.ID
    SelectTaskField Row:=wrkID, Column:="Number10", RowRelative:=False
    If wrkID = 23 Then
        a = 1
    End If

    Select Case tsk.Number10
        Case Is >= 9
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFF99CC
        Case Is >= 8
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&H66CCFF
        Case Is >= 7
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&H66FFFF
         Case Is = 0
             Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFFFFFF
    End Select

End If

Next n

SelectTaskField Row:="1", Column:="Number10", RowRelative:=False



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

Add this to the start of the subroutine

```
Dim wrkCHFlag As Boolean
wrkCHFlag = False
If EnableChangeHighlighting Then
   ToggleChangeHighlighting
   wrkCHFlag = True
End If`
```

and this to the end

```
If wrkCHFlag Then
    ToggleChangeHighlighting
End If
```

This [link](http://epmainc.com/blog/disable-change-highlighting-microsoft-project-2010-and-2013) explains Change Highlighting.  I discovered the VBA ToggleChangeHighlighting instruction via a macro, which led to the EnableChangeHighlighting property.